Link in Chrome browser that will open Android battery setings page
I want to create a Link that will take me from chrome browser to battery settings in my Android device:
I have the Link that takes me to settings,
intent://com.android.settings/#Intent;scheme=android-app;end

Now I want to make Link that will take me directly to battery page: Any ideas ?
I have the Link that takes me to settings,
intent://com.android.settings/#Intent;scheme=android-app;end

Need this to take me to the battery settings page directly
